# Multithreading a webscraper in python. Threading Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping, python-multithreading

I am trying to speed up my webscraper by implementing multithreading using the threading library but the runtime is no faster than when it was using a singlethread. I have tried to set up the craper so you can input the number of pages you want to scrape and/or the number of hops away from the original seed to go to.

```
import sys
import queue
import requests
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.robotparser import RobotFileParser
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
import statistics
import concurrent.futures

runtimes = []


def crawler(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory):
    f = open("report.txt", "w")
    f.write("")
    f.close()

    #multithreaded#
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
        executor.submit(crawler_thread, frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)

    #single threaded#
    # crawler_thread(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)



def crawler_thread(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory):

    while not frontier.empty() and req_pages > 0  and req_hops > 0:

        start_time0 = time.perf_counter()

        try:

            url = frontier.get()
            #print("Trying to Crawl: ", url)
            if url == '*': # denotes end of current hop has been hit
                req_hops = req_hops - 1
                frontier.put('*') # mark end of next hop
            elif crawl_permitted(url):
                parsed_url = urlparse(url)
                filename = parsed_url.netloc[4:] if parsed_url.netloc.find('www') == 0 else parsed_url.netloc
                filename = filename + parsed_url.path.replace('/', '-')

                if not already_saved(filename, output_directory):
                    response = requests.get(url, verify = False)
                    time.sleep(3)  #sleep for a few seconds for politeness. To do : implement politeness windows based on the host's crawl_delay specified robots.txt
                    open(output_directory + '/' + filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(response.text)     
                    req_pages = req_pages -1

                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
                    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

                        cleaned_link = clean_link(hyperlink = link.get('href'), website = url) 
                        if cleaned_link: 
                            frontier.put(cleaned_link)


        except:
            f = open("report.txt", "a")
            f.write("crawler failed on url: " + url) + "\n"
            f.close()

        end_time0 = time.perf_counter()
        runtimes.append(end_time0-start_time0)
        # refresh pages, robots.txt, politeness window - to do

#create url queue (frontier) parse argv to pass into crawler 
frontier = seeds_to_frontier(seeds_filename = sys.argv[1])
req_pages = int(sys.argv[2])
req_hops = int(sys.argv[3])
output_directory = sys.argv[4]

start_time1 = time.perf_counter()

#crawl
crawler(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)

end_time1 = time.perf_counter()

f = open("report.txt", "a")
f.write("Total Scrape Time: " +  str(end_time1-start_time1) + "\n")
f.write("Average Scrape Time for Each Url: " + str(statistics.mean(runtimes)) + "\n")  
f.close()

plt.plot(runtimes)
plt.ylabel("execution time (s)")
plt.xlabel("url queue iteration")
plt.title("scrapetime for each url")
plt.savefig("execution_time_of_scraped_urls")
```

Here are the extra functions I am using in the code above if you wanted to see them (but i don't think they are the reason for my bug):

```
def seeds_to_frontier(seeds_filename):
    seeds_file = open(seeds_filename, 'r') 

    frontier = queue.Queue()
    for page in seeds_file:
        frontier.put(page.strip('\n'))
    frontier.put('*') # marks end of hop 0

    seeds_file.close()
    return frontier

def crawl_permitted(url):
    rp = RobotFileParser()

    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    filename = parsed_url.netloc.rsplit('.', 2)[-2] + '.' + parsed_url.netloc.rsplit('.', 2)[-1]
    robots_url = parsed_url.scheme + '://' + filename + '/robots.txt'

    if not already_saved(filename, 'robots'):
        response = requests.get(robots_url)
        open('robots/' + filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(response.text)

    rp.set_url(robots_url)
    rp.read()   
    return rp.can_fetch('*', url)


def url_delay(url):
    rp = RobotFileParser()

    #set up url for robotfileparser
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    filename = parsed_url.netloc.rsplit('.', 2)[-2] + '.' + parsed_url.netloc.rsplit('.', 2)[-1]
    robots_url = parsed_url.scheme + '://' + filename + '/robots.txt'

    #parse the robots.txt and extract crawl_delay
    rp.set_url(robots_url)
    rp.read()
    crawl_delay = rp.crawl_delay("*") if rp.crawl_delay("*") else 0
    return crawl_delay


def already_saved(file, directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if file in files:
            return 1
    return 0

def clean_link(hyperlink, website): 
    parsed_website = urlparse(website)
    parsed_hyperlink = urlparse(hyperlink)
    cleaned_link = hyperlink

    if not parsed_hyperlink.scheme and not parsed_hyperlink.netloc and not parsed_hyperlink.path and not parsed_hyperlink.params \
        and not parsed_hyperlink.query and not parsed_hyperlink.fragment:
        return ''

    if parsed_hyperlink.scheme and parsed_hyperlink.scheme != 'http':
        return '' 

    if parsed_hyperlink.path == '/': # duplicate - self references
        return ''

    if parsed_hyperlink.fragment: # duplicate - bookmarks
        return ''

    # avoid pdfs, images,  # to do: The below solution is not the best to avoid all media
    if len(parsed_hyperlink.path) > 4 and (parsed_hyperlink.path[-4:] in [".pdf", ".jpg", ".png", ".svg", ".jpeg"]): 
        return ''

    # take care of invalid characters - to do

    if not (".edu" in parsed_hyperlink.netloc):# only crawl edu pages
        return ''

    if not parsed_hyperlink.netloc: 
        if parsed_hyperlink.path[0] == '/':
            cleaned_link = parsed_website.scheme + '://' + parsed_website.netloc + hyperlink
        else:
            # bug - hyperlink 'smi.ucr.edu' parsed as path and not netloc - ???
            if parsed_hyperlink.path[0:3] == 'tel:': # remove incorrectly formatted telephone links
                print('incorrect tel link: ' + hyperlink)
                return ''
            # double check
            cleaned_link = website + hyperlink

    return cleaned_link
```

The single threaded code works fine and scrapes a page on average at about 0.7 seconds. The multi threaded also scrapes at the same speed??? They way I initially set this up (shown above, first cell) seems to have been running a big loop in a single thread. I tried editing (code in cell below) to fix this.

```
def crawler(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory):
    f = open("report.txt", "w")
    f.write("")
    f.close()

    #multithreaded#
    # with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
    #   executor.submit(crawler_thread, frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)

    #single threaded#
    # crawler_thread(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)


    #testing stuff

    while not frontier.empty() and req_pages > 0  and req_hops > 0:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
            executor.submit(crawler_thread, frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)


def crawler_thread(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory):

    lock = threading.Lock()

    lock.acquire()
    if req_pages > 0  and req_hops > 0:

        lock.release()

        start_time0 = time.perf_counter()

        try:

            url = frontier.get()
            print("Trying to Crawl: ", url)
            if url == '*': # denotes end of current hop has been hit
                lock.acquire()
                req_hops = req_hops - 1
                lock.release()
                frontier.put('*') # mark end of next hop
            elif crawl_permitted(url):
                parsed_url = urlparse(url)
                filename = parsed_url.netloc[4:] if parsed_url.netloc.find('www') == 0 else parsed_url.netloc
                filename = filename + parsed_url.path.replace('/', '-')

                if not already_saved(filename, output_directory):
                    response = requests.get(url, verify = False)
                    #time.sleep(10)  #sleep for a few seconds for politeness. To do : implement politeness windows based on the host's crawl_delay specified robots.txt
                    open(output_directory + '/' + filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(response.text) 
                    lock.acquire()
                    req_pages = req_pages -1
                    lock.release()

                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
                    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

                        cleaned_link = clean_link(hyperlink = link.get('href'), website = url) 
                        if cleaned_link: 
                            frontier.put(cleaned_link)


        except:
            f = open("report.txt", "a")
            f.write("crawler failed on url: " + url + "\n")
            f.close()

        end_time0 = time.perf_counter()
        runtimes.append(end_time0-start_time0)
        # refresh pages, robots.txt, politeness window - to do

#create url queue (frontier) parse argv to pass into crawler 
frontier = seeds_to_frontier(seeds_filename = sys.argv[1])
req_pages = int(sys.argv[2])
req_hops = int(sys.argv[3])
output_directory = sys.argv[4]

start_time1 = time.perf_counter()

#crawl
crawler(frontier, req_pages, req_hops, output_directory)

end_time1 = time.perf_counter()

f = open("report.txt", "a")
f.write("Total Scrape Time: " +  str(end_time1-start_time1) + "\n")
f.write("Average Scrape Time for Each Url: " + str(statistics.mean(runtimes)) + "\n")  
f.close()

print("Total Scrape Time: " +  str(end_time1-start_time1) + "\n")

plt.plot(runtimes)
plt.ylabel("execution time (s)")
plt.xlabel("url queue iteration")
plt.title("scrapetime for each url")
plt.savefig("execution_time_of_scraped_urls")
```

1) I'm not sure if this is sped up. 
2) When I try to specify to stop after 10 pages scraped, the scraper keeps on going until i force quit it. The first version I have (cell 1) did not do this.

What is wrong with my first implementation and second implementation? The first one doesn't seem to be multithreaded at all due to the speed of the scraping. The second one (i'm not sure about the scrape speed yet) doesn't stop at the the req_page parameter. Where am i going wrong in my attempt to multithread this? Is my memory being corrupted?

Comment: If you need concurrency in Python, use Scrapy. If you are very confident that you know what you're doing you can try asyncio.

Comment: @pguardiario I thought Scrapy does not allow for multithreading?

Comment: It's not multithreading, it uses Twisted which does asynchronous downloading.